# Enumerate two lists at the same time

Tags: python, string, list, nlp, text-mining

I have two lists:
1.List of IPA symbols - M
2.List of single words - N

Now I need to create a third list X = [N,M] where for each IPA symbol found in a single word I have to assign 1 to the new list and 0. For example if M = ['ɓ', 'u', 'l', 'i', 'r', 't', 'ə', 'w', 'a', 'b'] and for simplicity N has only two words = ['ɓuli', 'rutə'], then the output should look like 
X = [[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]]

So it's kind of co-occurence matrix but simpler - because I do not need to hold count of how many times the symbol occur in the word. I just need to assign 1 to X when a symbol occur in a word in a proper position. Maybe I am overthinking this but I can't seem to find a way to hold index of both lists.
Here is my code snippet:

```
M = ['ɓ', 'u', 'l', 'i', 'r', 't', 'ə', 'w', 'a', 'b'] 
N = ['ɓuli', 'rutə']
X = np.zeros((len(N), len(M)))

for n_idx in range(len(N)):
    print('Current word index', n_idx)
    for symbol in N[n_idx]:
        if symbol in M:
            print(symbol, 'found, at word index', n_idx, ', and symbol index')
            # if found then ad to X at proper position

#Expected result
X = [[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
     [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build such an index with this line :

```
X = [[1 if e in s else 0 for e in M] for s in N]
```

which is a double comprehension list looping on letters and words. However you should use libraries such as sklearn to perform such operations more efficiently (e.g. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. Just loop the words that you need to check with other list and compare.

```
M=['a','e','i','o','u']
N=['stack','overflow']
output=[]
for words in N:
    words_output=[]
    for v in M:
        o = 1 if v in words else 0
        words_output.append(o)
    output.append(words_output)

output:
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: The output must always have the same length as M tho

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
M = ['ɓ', 'u', 'l', 'i', 'r', 't', 'ə', 'w', 'a', 'b'] 
N = ['ɓuli', 'rutə']
result = []
for n in N:
    tmp = []
    characters = list(n)
    for m in M:
        tmp.append(1 if m in characters else 0)
    result.append(tmp)
print(result)
#[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
# [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: btw you are recreating `list(n)` for each `m` in `M`. You could do that once next to `tmp`.

Comment: True, that'd be better. Thanks